# SQL query more time to execute and finally get error

Tags: mysql, sql, execution

```
UPDATE member
SET member.usableSum = (SELECT usablesum
        FROM fundrecord
        WHERE (member.id= fundrecord.memberId) AND id IN (
        SELECT MAX(id)
        FROM [enter image description here][1]fundrecord
        GROUP BY memberId)
        )
```

Comment: You're sub-query is only allowed to return one row here, but will probably return several rows.

Comment: Post the ERROR message.

Comment: Also add some sample data with your expected output from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you want:

```
UPDATE member m
    SET m.usableSum = (SELECT fr.usablesum
                       FROM fundrecord fr
                       WHERE m.id = fr.memberId
                       ORDER BY fr.id DESC
                       LIMIT 1
                      );
```

This returns the "most recent" `usablesum` from `fundrecord` for each member.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `DISTINCT` in your query,

```
UPDATE member
SET member.usableSum = (SELECT distinct usablesum
    FROM fundrecord
    WHERE (member.id= fundrecord.memberId) AND id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM [enter image description here][1]fundrecord
    GROUP BY memberId)
    )
```

If you are still facing same issue, then your subquery is returning multiple values